# Woocommerce Product images not showing on product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hope you are doing well, my site is [www.coutlet.com](http://www.coutlet.com), it's working fine but when I open any product page, the images are not showing. I've tried enabling disabling almost every plugin but that doesn't work. My woocommerce version is 4.7.0

these are the debug messages all of them are warnings.

```
Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /home4/heglqsmy/public_html/wp-content/plugins/hercules-core/translate/includes/class-hercules-wp-translate-po-parser.php on line 186

Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in /home4/heglqsmy/public_html/wp-content/plugins/masterslider/includes/classes/class-msp-main-widget.php on line 95

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /home4/heglqsmy/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/operations.class.php on line 2758

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /home4/heglqsmy/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/operations.class.php on line 2762

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /home4/heglqsmy/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/output.class.php on line 3706

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /home4/heglqsmy/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-product-addons/classes/class-product-addon-cart.php on line 321

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /home4/heglqsmy/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-product-addons/classes/class-product-addon-cart.php on line 338

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /home4/heglqsmy/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-product-addons/classes/class-product-addon-cart.php on line 371

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /home4/heglqsmy/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-product-addons/classes/class-product-addon-cart.php on line 390
```

Comment: Turn on debug mode and check if the debug log has any error.

Comment: I've added debug messages on my post

Comment: I've solved the problem, if someone else is having the same issue I want to let you guys know that after searching for the issue I saw that for some reason, div class "woocommerce-product-gallery" opacity was set to 0, I changed it to 100% using CSS and its showing again. Thank you melvin for your answer!

Comment: @Usman5251: why did you delete your answer? It's perfectly fine to post an answer to your own question if you find the solution. In fact, it's actively encouraged.

Comment: Right, I've undeleted it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem, if someone else is having the same issue I want to let you guys know that after searching for the issue I saw that for some reason, div class "woocommerce-product-gallery" opacity was set to 0, I changed it to 100% using CSS and its showing again. Thank you.